# I have a Raspberry Pi 4B and I'd like to make a NAS with it

Tags: raspberry-pi, nas

I've seen a few different bits & bobs that will let one add SATA to a Raspberry Pi, but I'd really love an enclosure that gives me 2x SATA and space for a couple 2.5" SSDs. Is there anything out there like that? I have not been successful in my web searches.

Edit: apologies, I didn't specify it's a 4B

Edit the Second: follow-up question, is there any advantage to a SATA HAT-oriented solution as opposed to just hooking up a RAID enclosure to the USB 3 port? It seems like the HATs all communicate over USB 3 anyway, so I'm not clear how the HAT would be any faster.

Comment: Pretty pricy, but "Argon EON" fits 4 discs apparently. (several youtube videos on it). P.s. anecdotally, the PI4 should be quite capable as a NAS... definitely way better than the 3, which from memory had a bottleneck going to Sata.

Comment: Which version of the Raspberry Pi do you have?

Comment: If you had a CM4, then something like https://pibox.io/ might be a nice option. They seem to be currently out of stock though.

Comment: Edited the question to note it's a 4B, thanks for pointing out my oversight @Romen

Comment: Are you doing this just for the fun of it, or do you have any specific design goals that are not met by the phletora of already available NAS solutions?